# Should we add a mod post guitars merge?

Tags: discussion, moderators

There were a couple of moderators who were doing an excellent job over at guitars prior to the merge. Should one (or two) of them be added as mods here in order to help with the transition of the guitars merge or is it good enough to have them as active members of the new site?

Comment: The mass of work due to the merge is over, and the three of us current mods are nowhere near being overwhelmed.  I would say there isn't enough mod work for adding another make sense yet.

Answer (score 2):

There will eventually be open moderator elections, and I'm sure there will be some Guitars.SE users up for that. I also know that the merge was held up until pro-temp moderators from music.SE were appointed... I'm not sure what the time frame is for the open elections, but if it's going to be significantly far off, perhaps there is some wisdom to appointing a transitional mod; @Rebecca Chernoff will have to chime in on that one.

Comment: Yes, I guess it really depends how long it takes to get to the community vote...

Comment: @yossarian Community moderator elections happen after a site graduates.